# special character or image in iOS app name

Tags: ios, unicode, special-characters, cfbundledisplayname

i was using the app APPS GONE FREE for finding free app
i was shocked to see the updated icon of APPS GONE FREE.
it has an image or special character written "free" within it,
i am a beginner in ios dev so don't know where to look.
how it is possible, can i do it in my app?

attaching the image url for reference.

***http://i41.tinypic.com/2ltjxco.png***

please guide!
 thanks in advance

Comment: Ugh, tinypic? Really? At least use imgur... Pretty sure they just made the icon like that. Also, this is an off-topic question.

Comment: sorry for tinypic ,
http://imgur.com/2TKNbRt 

that is not part of icon, i said it is in the app name that displayed on phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is am emoji character, available on the iOS emoji Keyboard:

Comment: thanks for the answer :)
can i make any character of my own (may be stupid thing to ask but curious)

Comment: You could, if you are using your own font. But the font for the Springboard icons is chosen by Apple.